# In Deep Learning "mxnet", restrict number of core (cpu)

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet

The command "ctx=mx.cpu()" is taking all available CPU. How to restrict to use a certain number only - say 6 out of 8 core

Comment: I don't think if there is an interface of such kind. Why do you actually need this? Anyways, [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569460/how-to-limit-pythons-use-of-cores-globally-in-ubuntu)

Comment: As of now, Deep learning algorithums in "mxnet" takes all available COREs and hence need the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately - no. Even though the cpu context has int as an [input argument](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/context.py#L106):

```
def cpu(device_id=0):
    """Returns a CPU context.
```

according to the official documentation:

```
 Parameters
 ----------
 device_id : int, optional
     The device id of the device. `device_id` is not needed for CPU.
     This is included to make interface compatible with GPU.
```

However, in theory, it might be changed in the future since the device_id argument is there. But for now MXNet takes all available cores.