# Limit number of CPUs using MXNET

Tags: python, gluon, mxnet

How can I set the number of CPUs to use in MXNET Gluon to a certain number, say 12?
I don't see the answer in the documentation anywhere and by default MXNET uses all the CPUs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Deep Learning "mxnet", restrict number of core (cpu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558127/in-deep-learning-mxnet-restrict-number-of-core-cpu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is impossible at the moment, but might be changed later.